# Get full error in Release mode in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, release, elmah

My MVC3 application that works fine in `Debug` is failing in `Release` mode. But the biggest problem is that the error I'm getting is not detailed at all. This is all I'm getting:

> Sorry, an error occurred while
>   processing your request.

I have configured `elmah` and was expecting to see a full error report, including stacktrace, there, but there's nothing.

How can I get a proper error report?

Comment: Is the release mode code also installed on a different server? What causes the error to occur, clicking a link?  Do you have the HandleError attribute in place or a suitable replacement that understands Elmah and passes exceptions on to it?

Comment: Check application event log on that server. You might be able to see a corresponding event there with more info about your error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After @tvanfosson comment, I realized I hadn't configured MVC3 to pass exceptions to `elmah`. Found [this tutorial](http://joel.net/wordpress/index.php/2011/02/logging-errors-with-elmah-in-asp-net-mvc3-part1/) on how to do it, and right on Part 1 it suggests to comment this line from Global.asax.cs:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    //filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

That did it. Getting the YSOD now, and `elmah` correctly captures the exception.

Comment: That tutorial is a great walkthrough of setting up elmah.